# Enabling FormBuilder/SearchKit I get error message Duplicate entry 'search_display_type' for key 'civicrm_option_group.UI_name'

Tags: error, formbuilder

I've moved a site from D7 to D10 and it's gone pretty well. However, I have an error message that I can't figure out.

When I enabled FormBuilder and Form Core, I get the following message:

`Duplicate entry 'search_display_type' for key 'civicrm_option_group.UI_name'`

I have checked the civicrm_option_group table and there's defintely only one entry with that name.

I reset the paths and got a similar message:

`Duplicate entry 'civicrm/admin/options/activity_type-1' for key 'civicrm_menu.UI_path_domain_id'`

Again, I've checked the civicrm_menu table and there's definitely only a single entry with the path civicrm/admin/options/activity_type

Where should I be looking to see why these errors are triggered? There's nothing wrong in the tables themselves so it's coming from somewhere else??

I don't know if it's linked to FormBuilder but that's the only way I've found that reliably triggers the message.

Comment: This sounds like the usual managed entities fight. I would start by deleting those two database entries from the tables and let it try to recreate them, or try to force it to recreate them by going to `civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1`